# Can you create an object in Javascript without declaring every value, and how?

Tags: javascript, variables, object, declaration

I want to do the following:

```
var Room = function(name, north, south, east, west) {
    this.name = name;
    this.north = north;
    this.south = south;
    this.west = west;
    this.east = east;
}
```

Where north, south, east and west is just a flag saying if there is a door there.

When I create an object I have to do this:

```
var bedroom = new Room('Bedroom', true, false, false, false);
```

I was wondering if there is a way so that I can just say which directions have a true value such as:

```
var bedroom = new Room({
    name: 'Bedroom',
    north: true
});
```

With **south, east, and west becoming false.**  This way if I were to have say 20 different options I would only have to specify the ones I care about, instead of having a long declarations with a lot of false and '' values and I wouldn't need to remember which order they were suppose to be in (north, south, east, west? or north, east, south, west?),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need separate instance variables for `north`, `south`, `east` and `west`, I'd suggest something like this where you can pass just the directions that you care about in a space delimited string.  This makes the calling code much simpler since you don't have to pass anything for the directions that don't exist.

```
var Room = function(name, directions) {
    this.name = name;
    this.north = this.south = this.west = this.east = false;
    directions = directions.split(" ");
    directions.forEach(function(item) {
        this[item] = true;
    })
}

var bedroom = new Room('Bedroom', 'north south');
```

---

Or, your object approach works fine too:

```
var Room = function(name, directions) {
    this.name = name;
    this.north = this.south = this.west = this.east = false;
    for (var dir in directions) {
        this[dir] = directions[dir];
    }
}

var bedroom = new Room('Bedroom', {north: true, south: true});
```

---

A third approach is to use flags (often used in C/C++).  This allows you to pass an arbitrary number of flags in a single value:

```
var Room = function(name, directions) {
    this.name = name;
    this.directions = directions;
}

Room.prototype = {
   isNorth: function() { return this.directions & Room.north},
   isSouth: function() { return this.directions & Room.south},
   isWest: function() { return this.directions & Room.west},
   isEast: function() { return this.directions & Room.east},
};

Room.north = 1;
Room.south = 2;
Room.east = 4;
Room.west = 8;

var bedroom = new Room('Bedroom', Room.north | Room.south);
```

Comment: What if both north and south should be true?

Comment: @j08691 - I didn't originally realize that was a requirement.  I've modified my answer to support that now.

Comment: The space-separated string is a little idiosyncratic (ie, it's now how you'd do things in many other situations), but in this case it's kind of cute.

Comment: Thanks, after trying the others, this one seemed to work the best for me!

Comment: @JonathanOwenChute - I added a third version that uses binary flags.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Thanks, the object approach makes the most logical sense to me and is working like a charm, I appreciate all the work!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript Objects

Add in a default value with the `||` operator

```
var Room = function(name, north, south, east, west) {
    this.name = name;
    this.north = north || false;
    this.south = south || false;
    this.west = west || false;
    this.east = east || false;
}
```

This will tell it to use `east` if data was supplied for it or use false if `east` turns out to be `undefined`.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the question was to not have to pass all the directions at once in the constructor.  That does seem kind of silly.

Comment: Just be careful about using this way of assigning default values with `true` and `false`. It will work in this direction, but you can't assign false values with truthy defaults this way.

Answer (score 3):

```
var Room = function (options) {
    this.name = options.name;
    var cardinals = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west'];

    // Check your directions param for each of the cardinal directions
    // that you want to allow
    cardinals.forEach(function (direction) {
        if (typeof options[direction] !== 'undefined') {
            this[direction] = options[direction];
        } else {
            this[direction] = false;
        }
    });
};

var room = new Room({ name: 'Bedroom', north: true, south: true });
```

Comment: It is not recommended to iterate an array in Javascript with `for (var direction in cardinals)` as this iterates all properties of the array, not only array elements and could include any enumerable polyfill methods or custom methods added to the Array object.  Instead, use `.forEach()` or the style `for (var i = 0; i < cardinals.length; i++)`.

Comment: Agreed! Not sure why I used that way originally; absent-mindedness? I've updated my example for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "for .. in ..." loop to iterate input object with params. Example:

```
Room = function(options) {
    for (var key in options) {
        this[key] = options[key];
    }
}

var bedroom = new Room({
    name: 'Bedroom',
    north: true
});
```

Comment: I think I'll switch to this approach once `for .. of ..` is supported everywhere. I like the way that any other value is `undefined`, but using `for .. in ..` has it's problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `||` operator

e.g.

```
var Room = function(name, directions) {
    this.name = name;
    this.north = directions.north || false;
    this.south = directions.south || false;
    this.west = directions.west || false;
    this.east = directions.east || false;
}
```

then when you call `var r = new Room("something", {north:true});` all the other values will be set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some sort of subclass.

In main class you put all default values.

```
function AbstractRoom(name, north, south, east, west){
    this.name = name;
    this.north = north;
    this.south= south;
    this.east= east;
    this.west= west;
}
```

In your sub-class you put your values

```
function RoomNorth(name){
  AbstractRoom.call(this, name, true, false, false, false);
}
```

in this case

```
var myNorthRoom = new RoomNorth('AGoodName');
```

where

```
myNorthRoom.north <-- true
myNorthRoom.south <-- false
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var Room = function( name, directions ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.north = directions.north || false;
    this.south = directions.south || false;
    this.west = directions.west || false;
    this.east = directions.east || false;
}
```

And then calling the constructor like:

```
var bedroom = new Room( 'Bedroom', { 'north': true } );
```

If you don't define a direction the || operator will make it false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using a "chaining" pattern (it's not a builder per-se):

```
function Room (name) {
   this.name = name;
}

Room.prototype = {
   north: function (v) {
       if (arguments.length > 0 } { this._north = v; return this; }
       else { return this._north; }
   },
   south: function (v) {
       if (arguments.length > 0 } { this._south = v; return this; }
       else { return this._south; }
   },
   // .. rest of getter-setters
   // The prototype can be used for defaults and/or lifting
   _north: false,
   _south: false,
   // .. rest of defaults
}

var room = new Room("bedroom")
  .north(true)
  .south(true); // => the Room object

var hasNorth = room.north(); // => true
```

Some people might not like this pattern - and especially this implementation - because it changes the return type of the getter/setter to be "sometimes-chainable" and "sometimes-return-the-value", like some jQuery methods (eg. `$.val`).

It also requires / encourages that the directions (eg. "north") be accessed via getter methods. Defining properties doesn't allow such chaining syntax.